# Why am I getting error when I make a sibling module in Go?

Tags: go, dependencies, go-modules

Here's my filesystem:

```
Go/
  HelloWorld/
    go.mod
    go.sum
    hello.go
  GoQuote/
    go.mod
```

I installed the module, here's my HelloWorld/go.mod:

```
module example/hello

go 1.21.3

require (
    golang.org/x/text v0.0.0-20170915032832-14c0d48ead0c // indirect
    rsc.io/quote/v4 v4.0.1
    rsc.io/sampler v1.3.0 // indirect
)
```

and go.sum:

```
golang.org/x/text v0.0.0-20170915032832-14c0d48ead0c h1:qgOY6WgZOaTkIIMiVjBQcw93ERBE4m30iBm00nkL0i8=
golang.org/x/text v0.0.0-20170915032832-14c0d48ead0c/go.mod h1:NqM8EUOU14njkJ3fqMW+pc6Ldnwhi/IjpwHt7yyuwOQ=
rsc.io/quote/v4 v4.0.1 h1:i/LHLEinr65wwTCqlP4OnMoMWeCgnFIZFvifdXNK+5M=
rsc.io/quote/v4 v4.0.1/go.mod h1:w/DafQky66grMesu3uPhdDMS3knhBippwwemZtMOyCI=
rsc.io/sampler v1.3.0 h1:7uVkIFmeBqHfdjD+gZwtXXI+RODJ2Wc4O7MPEh/QiW4=
rsc.io/sampler v1.3.0/go.mod h1:T1hPZKmBbMNahiBKFy5HrXp6adAjACjK9JXDnKaTXpA=
```

Here are the errors:
`could not import rsc.io/quote/v4 (cannot find package "rsc.io/quote/v4" in GOROOT or GOPATH)compilerBrokenImport`
and
`undefined: quotecompilerUndeclaredName`

There were no errors until I created the GoQuote directory and ran the `go mod init example.com/GoQuote` command.
I'm new to Go (first hour!) and don't know what the problem is.

I tried saving all my files (I'm in VS code), but it didn't work.

Comment: Check your go env. Especially your GOROOT/GOPATH variable. 
run: `go env`

Comment: can you please explain steps you have gone sequentially? I assumed you successfully compiles hello package and then changed your directory in console to quote folder and then you run **go mod init example/quote** and then **go mod tidy**. am I right?

Comment: "and ran the mod command" There is no "mod command". Please show exactly what you type where and the exact output. E.g. it is unclear which command leads to the "could not import rsc.io/quote/v4 ..." error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It looks like the problem was the structure of the filesystem... If I change it to be

```
Go/
  go.mod
  go.sum
  hello.go
GoQuote/
  go.mod
```

then there are no errors.